# Aiuto con verbi copulativi

Tags: grammar, verbs, auxiliary-verb

Sarebbe corretto il verbo "considerare/definire/reputare" in queste frasi?

Partiamo dalle possibili costruzioni grammaticali che si possono fare con verbi come "essere" e "sembrare:

1. Come sembro/sono? Sembro/sono alto.
2. Cosa sembro/sono? Sembro/sono un disastro.
3. Chi sembro/sono? Sembro/sono Marco.
4. Quanta sembra/è l'acqua? L'acqua sembra/è davvero tantissima

Io mi chiedo: 
si possono fare esempi simili con verbi copulativi quali considerare, ritenere, definire ecc...?
Vi riporto gli stessi esempi di prima:

5. Come mi consideri/ritieni/definisci? Ti ritengo alto.
6. Cosa mi consideri/reputi/definisci? Ti definisco/reputo un disastro.
7. Chi mi ritieni/reputi? Ti reputo Marco
8. Quanta consideri l'acqua? L'acqua la considero tantissima.

Parliamo sempre di verbi copulativi, ma le ultime due frasi mi sembrano agrammaticali.

Answer (score 3):

Sì, le tue frasi 5-8 sono perfettamente corrette.

Il motivo per cui la 7 sembra un po' strana è perché il verbo *reputare* è raramente usato per identificare l'identità delle persone, ma grammaticalmente non fa una grinza.

Per la frase 8, probabilmente riordinerei le parole un pochino (*Considero l'acqua tantissima*) per far fluire meglio il discorso, ma non vedo problemi grammaticali qui.

Comment: Sono d’accordo sull’esempio 7. Sulla domanda dell’esempio 8 credo che difficilmente si direbbe così. Suona meglio, forse: «Quanta consideri che sia l’acqua?». Vale la pena, a mio parere, tenere conto dei due aspetti: correttezza grammaticale e uso. L’uso, mi preme dirlo, non significa necessariamente “basso, non adeguato”.

Comment: @Benedetta Sono d'accordo che le frasi siano tutte un po' innaturali, ma mi premeva soprattutto insistere sulla loro correttezza grammaticale più che sulla loro idiomaticità (cfr. *Considero l'acqua essenziale per un campo base*, che forse è leggermente più idiomatica)

Comment: (Non riesco a menzionare @Denis Nardin, non so perché) Ho dato un voto favorevole alla tua risposta proprio perché è adeguata alla domanda.

Comment: @Denis Nardin♦: Quando parli di frasi innaturali a quali ri riferisci di preciso? Ps mi scuso per aver risposto in ritardo.

Comment: @Nakamura Come ho detto, l'uso del verbo *reputare* con le persone è un po' desueto. Inoltre è difficile (ma non impossibile) immaginare un contesto in cui qualcuno userebbe la 8 (frasi più idiomatiche sarebbero *ritengo l'acqua tantissima* o *mi sembra che l'acqua sia tantissima*). In generale l'uso dell'inversione con il complemento oggetto prima del verbo è un po' meno naturale in italiano, sebbene non assente.

Comment: Denis Nardin♦: Si, capisco.  Ma prima tu dicevi che le frasi sono tutte un po' innaturali, ma cmq corrette. A QUALI frasi ti riferivi nello specifico?